# Getting itemListener() error in GUI using AWT

Tags: java, user-interface, awt, itemlistener

I am getting an error on "Mycheckbox" class extends Frame implements ItemListener:

> The type Mycheckbox must implement the inherited abstract method
>   ItemListener.itemStateChanged(ItemEvent)

I'm using AWT for coding GUI in my program:

```
import java.io.*;     
import java.awt.Checkbox;   
import java.awt.FlowLayout;   
import java.awt.Frame;        
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.event.*;  

class Mycheckbox extends Frame implements ItemListener {

    String msg="";
    Checkbox c1,c2,c3;

    Mycheckbox(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        c1=new Checkbox("Bold",true);
        c2=new Checkbox("Italic");
        c3=new Checkbox("Underline");

        add(c1);
        add(c2);
        add(c3);

        c1.addItemListener(this);
        c2.addItemListener(this);
        c3.addItemListener(this);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){              
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
                System.exit(0);
            }                   
        });                     
    }

    public void ItemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("Current state",10,100);
        msg="Bold:" +c1.getState();
        g.drawString(msg,10,100);
        msg="Italic:" +c2.getState();
        g.drawString(msg,10,100);
        msg="Underline:" +c3.getState();
        g.drawString(msg,10,160);       
    }       

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Mycheckbox mc=new Mycheckbox();
        mc.setSize(400,400);
        mc.setTitle("check box");
        mc.setVisible(true);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is case sensitive: Compiler is clearly telling you to implement a method named `itemStateChanged` and you decided to implement `ItemStateChanged` with an upper case `I`. Hence according to compiler `itemStateChanged` is not implemented.

Comment: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.